# Cannot connect to ubuntu folder in windows

Tags: networking, permissions

What is the command in Ubuntu to display folder permissions
The pathway to the folder in ubuntu is
/home/username/nameoffolder

I use the ls command and the result says Total 0
I suppose that means there are no files within that folder.

I want to display that folder in windows. I can connect to the ubuntu network in windows by typing \192.168.1.5 or with using the server name. But I cannot map a drive in windows to the folder I created in ubuntu.

Do I have to add some permissions to the folder in ubuntu before windows sees it. I installed samba and net-tools to ubuntu which allowed windows to see ubuntu computer but not the folders.

Comment: Are you running in a dual boot local environment, or is Ubuntu located on a remote server?

Comment: No its on a stand alone pc connected to my network

Comment: I ran the command sudo chmod 0777 /nameoffolder but error says no such file or directory

Comment: WSL2 should work. Just set up an Ubuntu env in Windows, and the 2 should be able to communicate via tcp/ip.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cannot "see" a linux folder. They each use different technologies to store data. Windows uses NTFS and Ubuntu uses ext4. Your best bet would be to use something like ftp to transfer files inside your network.

That said, if you download WSL2, you will have a linux environment inside Windows. You may be able to use bash from inside WSL2 to connect, and even mount your folder.

Comment: Previously my windows pc was able to map to a folder that was on ubuntu without needing to use any ftp programme or needing to have some linux environment installed on windows. But I have a new harddrive. Previously the mapping in windows was \\192.168.1.3\nameoffolder. And all the files were displayed. I want to set up the same again. I don't know how it was setup initially as someone else did it.